# Why does a balloon filled with air weigh more than an empty balloon

Tags: ideal-gas, buoyancy

A common experiment to demonstrate that air has weight is to weigh a deflated balloon and an inflated one. The deflated balloon gives a lower reading on the balance and hence we conclude that air has weight.

However, if we think about it, what we have done is just 'encase' a part of the atmosphere inside the balloon. When the air was outside the balloon it had no 'weight'. If we hold a weighing machine in the air, it reads $0$. Why does putting the air inside a balloon suddenly give it mass?

In other words, if the air inside the balloon exactly displaces its mass of air. So the force due to gravity on it must be cancelled with the upthrust due to buoyancy. How then does the balloon filled with air weight more?

Comment: the only balloons that I have played with were made of elastic rubber, so that, once filled with air, they also squeezed it inside. Hence in a balloon you get denser air than the surrounding. Archimedes would then say "Eureka!" I suppose...

Comment: Why does a filled LPG cylinder weigh more than an empty cylinder? The purpose of the experiment is to show that air or gases have mass.

Comment: Correct point but bad example:  the L in LPG stands for Liquid

Comment: Difference is the gas is under more pressure in the cylinder than the air in the balloon.